# Java - Chat with multiple machine

Tags: java, multithreading, socket.io, chat, serversocket

I'm not talking about room chat.
What I want is that we can chat to many peeple from many machines in many JFrames and importantly at the same time, like Yahoo or Skype.
I can do it when 1 machine connects to 1 machine only.
I started learning about computer networking in Java a couple weeks ago so I just know to use a few things like `Thread`, `ServerSocket`, `Socket`. With those only, is it possible to do that??
And if it could be done, how ??
Thank you for your time and sorry for my bad English

Comment: What you have so far?

Comment: you can do it using only those..

Comment: Please post what you've tried or some code. simply asking 'how' is to broad.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes it is possible.  However there are alternatives.

This is a bit of a broad topic so I apologize for the somewhat broad answer.  In this situation I would recommend a messaging server like [rabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/).  RabbitMQ and servers like it use a publish/subscribe model to send and receive data.  Once you have a server you just need a messaging client to send/receive messages to the server.  They handle a lot of the mess for you and there are plugins/modules/APIs for pretty much every language.

This approach would also allow users to only see messages from users they want to see.  If you want everyone to see everything you could just have each user subscribe to every other user.